# Why does the color change when an image is copied from Edge and pasted into PowerPoint, Paint, Excel but not Word

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

We have a C# and JavaScript application that uses chart.js to create a chart.  We have a requirement to copy that image to the clipboard to be pasted into PowerPoint.

Because of security limitations in JavaScript our solution was to take the chart and convert it into an image using toBase64Image and displaying that image in a popup window created in JavaScript.  The the user can use Edge or IE11 to right-click and select Copy or Copy Image (depending on the browser) so that they then can paste it into PowerPoint.

The problem occurs when the image is pasted into PowerPoint, Paint or Excel (it works fine in Word).  The background color changes from white to black.  It is not a negative image because all of the other colors of the image remain the same.  The problem is that some of the parts of the graph are black to begin with and with a black background they are lost.

I looked for code to change the background color preemptively to see if that would help but I haven't been successful in implementing any code that I have found yet.

What I need is to be able to copy the image and paste it into PowerPoint with a white background.

Comment: Some programs have a problem with transparency. What is happing if you copy the image from Word to Paint? JPEGs cannot be transparent.

Comment: At a glance, it's likely that your image is transparent, which causes the pixels that aren't filled in to be black in some environments. However, more information is needed to be sure.

Comment: @Terus If I copy the image from Word to Paint, etc then everything works fine.  The white background stays white.

Comment: @Yidna That sounds logical.  If you know of a solution to changing the transparency then please let me know.  If not then I will begin searching for that solution online.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent backgrounds occasionally show up as black.

[This chart.js GH issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2830) has snippet of code for setting the background colour.

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chartInstance) {
    var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chartInstance.chart.width, chartInstance.chart.height);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am looking at how to implement this code.  I didn't write the code that uses chart.js and prior to this task I have no experience with it.  There is a whole lot that I have yet to understand about this whole structure.

Comment: Awesome!  I got it working and it works perfectly.  Thank you very much.